# access vba: go to next iteration on error

Tags: vba, ms-access, for-loop, error-handling, resume

Listbox2 is populated from items in a table, which itself is populated from listbox1. An error will be thrown if an attempted addition to the table contains duplicate keys. I want my code to handle the error by skipping the problem iteration in question,  instead of stopping halfway through the loop.

My code looks something like this:

```
Public Sub CopySelected(ByRef frm As Form)

    Dim ctlSource As Control
    Dim intCurrentRow As Integer

    Set ctlSource = Me!listbox1
On Error GoTo nonrelation
    Dim rst As dao.Recordset
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from [tempTable]")

    For intCurrentRow = 0 To ctlSource.ListCount - 1
        If ctlSource.Selected(intCurrentRow) Then
            rst.AddNew
            rst![field1] = Forms![myForm]![listbox1].Column(1, intCurrentRow)
            rst![field2] = Forms![myForm]![listbox1].Column(0, intCurrentRow)
            rst.Update
            Forms![myForm]!listbox2.Requery
        End If
    Next intCurrentRow
    Forms![myForm]!listbox2.Requery
done:
    Exit Sub
nonrelation:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

I know I have to use a 'resume' command somehow in place of my `MsgBox Err.Description`, but I've never used it. I would like to know how to properly implement that into my code. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can just place your `nonnrelation:` above `Next intCurrentRow` to move to the next item.

Comment: Why do you not modify the query in order to not take across duplicates? Seems more proper to me. Error handling should be reserved to handle real errors

Comment: I mean, the query does not accept duplicates. It is not possible to insert duplicates into tempTable, and thus impossible in listbox2. However, an error will be thrown if it is attempted. I don't know if I'm understanding your comment, though.

Comment: Also @dwirony I cannot place 'nonrelation' above  'Next intCurrentRow'; my code gets gets thrown into a loop that's hard to get out of, without using the pause/break button on my keyboard

Comment: Add a label before `Next`, say, `skip:` - then add `Resume skip` under the `MsgBox` call. That said, @OleEHDufour has a very true and important point: error handling shouldn't be used for control flow. What's the error? Can it be avoided altogether?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks, worked like a charm! Note taken..but still not sure how I would avoid using an error handler though. The error thrown would be a duplicate primary key error thrown from an attempt to insert a duplicate item into listbox2. If the user does not make a mistake, no error is thrown.

Comment: Golden rule #1: users don't make mistakes, programmers do! ;-)  looks like you need additional logic to verify whether you're about to insert a duplicate key. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the record exists with a helper function and only add if not.

```
Public Function Exists(ByVal Value As String) As Boolean
    Exists = DCount("*","tempTable","[field1]='" & Value & "'") > 0
End Function
```

Then inside your loop check each record before attempting to insert.

```
For intCurrentRow = 0 To ctlSource.ListCount - 1
    If ctlSource.Selected(intCurrentRow) Then
        If Not Exists(Forms![myForm]![listbox1].Column(1, intCurrentRow)) Then
            With rst
                .AddNew
                ![field1] = Forms![myForm]![listbox1].Column(1, intCurrentRow)
                ![field2] = Forms![myForm]![listbox1].Column(0, intCurrentRow)
                .Update
            End With
            Forms![myForm]!listbox2.Requery
        End If
    End If
Next intCurrentRow
```

Note the above example expects a `String`. In case of a numeric, you will need to remove the `'` `'` quotes.